# Is it correct to say - "I owned it for 3 years ,before selling it."?. Or: "I owned it for 3 years before I sold it."?

Tags: grammar, tense

Is it correct to say: "I owned it for 3 years before selling it"? Or should we say: "I owned it for 3 years before I sold it"? Or should we say "I had owned it for 3 years before I sold it.
I'm confused about whether we can use the 1st sentence as we were using a present continuous sentence with a past one.

Comment: There is no present continuous in your sentences.

Comment: "I owned it for 3 years before selling it" suggests more focus on the process of selling, while "I owned it for 3 years before I sold it" suggests the focus is on you no longer possessing it. "I had owned it for 3 years before I sold it" would fit in a past-tense narration. This is all standard English grammar, the normal use of tenses: it's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

These are both acceptable. "Sold" is the past participle, which possibly suggests a bit more of "depth of time" -- but this is extremely subtle. I don't believe there's any significant difference to a native speaker.

Answer (score -1):

The first two are good and exactly equivalent in meaning.

The third one's pluperfect+ simple past match is very unlikely.

Comment: But, why can't we use the third sentence?Isn't it the exact definition of past perfect (a past action before another past action)?

Comment: @Arjun Actually you can, if you are talking about something that happened quite some time ago. For instance "I had a Cadillac in the late 1980s but I needed money early in the 90s. I had owned it for five years before I sold it."

Comment: @BoldBen While it's plausible that someone might say that, consider that it's strictly worse than the fully coordinated "*I'd* sold it".

Comment: @Arjun "I had owned it for three years before I sold it" is looking back on the past. Almost story-telling. The differences are really subtle. However, if I heard "I..had..sold" I would *possibly* understand more of a gap in time than "I owned it..." -- This is quite complicated stuff and I would encourage you to read this Wikipedia article (or their list of sources):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood